# Understanding この足場のやつにしろお互い六道仙人の力の恩恵だ

Tags: grammar, manga

Here is an excerpt from Naruto chapter 681.

[image]

I have trouble with this sentence この足場のやつにしろお互い六道仙人の力の恩恵だ. First, I am not sure if this にしろ means にしても or is an imperative form for にする. I suspect the former makes more sense since Naruto already summoned 足場. I also have doubt with the word お互い. I initially thought it refers to Sasuke and Naruto working together but I think it would be better to refer to Sasuke and 六道仙人...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Yes, this にしろ is the same as にせよ/にしても. The imperative reading makes little sense to me.
- This お互い means "we both". It indicates the two people in the scene *both* have received some blessing from the 仙人. Note that this type of お互い(に) does *not* indicate they are doing something mutually or together. For example, you can say お互い(に)頑張りましょう ("Let's both do our best") even when you're working towards completely different goals. お互い(に)結婚しています means "We're both married", while お互い**と**結婚しています means "We've married each other".